# Tabla de datos temporal en memoria de la computadora cliente

Tags: php, mysql

Soy programador de Delphi y sé que los clientdataset crean tablas temporales con distintas funciones para no tener que consultar al servidor de base de datos por cada filtro realizado.

Busqué cómo hacer lo mismo en php, o sea, si hacemos una búsqueda incremental, por cada letra se realizaría una consulta lo cual es una carga para el servidor php y Mysql.

Entonces: ¿se pueden tener los datos en local, en la máquina cliente, y ahí filtrar?

Por otro lado, si se sale de la página ¿se puede no volver a realizar el select general de todos los registros?

Comment: Se me ocurre que podrías, en algún momento inicial de la aplicación, o incluso en un proceso separado, hacer una consulta de toda la base de datos (o de la parte que necesites) y "descargarla" en formato JSON por ejemplo. 

Al tenerlo todo en JSON en memoria o ficheros locales, lo tienes accesible más rápido que lanzando cada vez la consulta contra el servidor mysql.

Comment: Debes tener en cuenta que la "computadora cliente" es un navegador web y no tu servidor web PHP, por lo que el único lenguaje en el que se puede desarrollar los que solicitas es en javascript y no PHP, independientemente del motor de bases de datos que use tu servidor (mysql en tu caso). Existen numerosos frameworks que te permiten filtrado en el navegador. Un ejemplo lo proporciona `filter` de angular.js: [pulsa en este enlace para ver un ejemplo](https://plnkr.co/edit/5T7sTAb6VQcfz76MKD5z?p=preview).

Comment: Gracias a los dos. No uso frameworks, pero ya me queda claro que debo descargar todo del lado del cliente y trabajar con javascript por ejemplo..

Comment: Y como se haria para crear un ticket en un sistema de facturacion? El ticket es un registro temporal..no se puede estar insertando y/o eliminando. solo manejarse, es decir recorrer luego la tabla visual de html